# Concatenate Tibbles and Print Plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two tibbles of plots that look like this:

```
>result
# A tibble: 11 x 3
   Gene      data             plots 
   <fct>     <list>           <list>
 1 MsLHCA6   <tibble [5 × 2]> <gg>  
 2 MsLHCB1.1 <tibble [5 × 2]> <gg>  
 3 MsPLGG1-A <tibble [5 × 2]> <gg>  
 4 MsPSBTN   <tibble [5 × 2]> <gg>  
 5 MsCFBP1-A <tibble [5 × 2]> <gg>  
 6 MsPGK1    <tibble [5 × 2]> <gg>  
 7 MsRPI1-B  <tibble [5 × 2]> <gg>  
 8 MsRPI3-B  <tibble [5 × 2]> <gg>  
 9 MsTKL-1   <tibble [5 × 2]> <gg>  
10 MsRCA-A   <tibble [5 × 2]> <gg>  
11 MsCRD1-B  <tibble [5 × 2]> <gg>  

>result.lfc
# A tibble: 11 x 3
   Gene.Name data              plots 
   <fct>     <list>            <list>
 1 MsLHCB1.1 <tibble [10 × 9]> <gg>  
 2 MsLHCA6   <tibble [10 × 9]> <gg>  
 3 MsPLGG1-A <tibble [10 × 9]> <gg>  
 4 MsRPI3-B  <tibble [10 × 9]> <gg>  
 5 MsRPI1-B  <tibble [10 × 9]> <gg>  
 6 MsPGK1    <tibble [10 × 9]> <gg>  
 7 MsCFBP1-A <tibble [10 × 9]> <gg>  
 8 MsPSBTN   <tibble [10 × 9]> <gg>  
 9 MsTKL-1   <tibble [10 × 9]> <gg>  
10 MsRCA-A   <tibble [10 × 9]> <gg>  
11 MsCRD1-B  <tibble [10 × 9]> <gg>
```

Is there any way to merge the plots columns of the tibbles? I would like to take the plots with the same Gene.Name and use this function:

```
fpkm.and.lfc = function(x,y){
  for(i in seq_along(x$Gene.Name)){
    print(i)
  ggarrange(x$plots[[i]], y$plots[[i]], ncol = 1, heights = c(.4,1), align = "v")
  ggsave(paste0(x$Gene.Name[[i]],"_Plots.png"), height = 20, width = 20, units = "cm")}
}
print.plots = fpkm.and.lfc(result, result.lfc)
```

This function works but I was wondering if folks had suggestions for a more efficient piece of code?

Comment: Your two `Gene.Name` vectors don't match, so your function doesn't pair plots correctly when you pass `result` and `result.lfc`. What do you actually want to do? Merge the tibbles, permute the rows of one of the tibbles so that it is ordered like the other, modify the function so that it can handle differently ordered tibbles...?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is pair and print the `ggplot` objects, then actually merging the tibbles isn't necessary. All you really need is `match`:

```r
function(x, y) {
  m <- match(x$Gene.Name, y$Gene.Name)
  for (i in which(!is.na(m))) {
    ## plot x$plots[[i]] and y$plots[[m[i]]]
  }
}
```

You can replace `which(!is.na(m))` with `seq_along(m)` if you know that the names in `x$Gene.Name` are all found in `y$Gene.Name`, in which case `m` would not contain `NA`.